# Will purging listener_scan1.log, listener_scan2.log, listener_scan3.log in Oracle 12C RAC Configuration not affect database services negatively

Tags: oracle, linux

I have a got a oracle 12c database configuration where there is RAC configuration for DB01 on one server and DB02 on another server. The issue i have is that the  listener_scan1.log, listener_scan2.log, listener_scan3.log are too big from 1Gig to 8Gig and i need to clear the log contents without deleting the files.

The last time i cleared the log contents via linux command:  du -sh asmnet1lsnr_asm.log , du -sh listener_scan1.log , du -sh listener_scan2.log, du -sh listener_scan3.log, and also manually deleted the .trc, .trm, .aud files i ended up with a database where i cant even even log into via clients like PLSQL or Oracle SQL Developer and i am only logging in via ssh.

So please advise before i mess things even worse.

Comment: the `du` command doesn't clear file content. it only reports file size. you should be able to rotate the log files and remove old trace files, etc., without impacting the database. If you can't login to the database, it may be because there's no space left on your storage to make new log or audit entries and services are frozen.

Comment: Sorry i meant to say i clear the log files by the command:  [root@db01 ~]# : > asmnet1lsnr_asm.log or [root@db01 ~]# : > listener_scan1.log or [root@db01 ~]# : > or [root@db01 ~]# : > listener_scan2.log or [root@db01 ~]# : > listener_scan3.log and i am saying if i clear log files this way is this safe?

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete the file but truncate them.

```
> /your/log/file
```

This way you free the space occupied and also keep a descriptor to the file. If you just delete a file it will be delete for your session but if an other process, for example a listener keeps it open at all times, the space won't be reclaimed for the OS.

By truncating logfiles you normally won't have a negative influence on the persformance .... In contrary.

Comment: Sorry i meant to say i clear the log files by the command: [root@db01 ~]# : > asmnet1lsnr_asm.log or [root@db01 ~]# : > listener_scan1.log or [root@db01 ~]# : > or [root@db01 ~]# : > listener_scan2.log or [root@db01 ~]# : > listener_scan3.log and i am saying if i clear log files this way is this safe?

Comment: As long as you make sure they don’t end up as being owned by root.